# HTML Footer is not in the bottom and content is over it.

Tags: html, css

i don't found it in the forum... So my question is:

I got a footer on my page. This footer is actually on the ground thats right. 
But if i resize the page and i have to scroll down. The footer is not anymore at the bottom and the content is under the footer.

[Can you help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3asg.png)

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: show your code or add a link to your website.

Comment: Sorry i forgot.   Www.baddog.me/register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `position: absolute`, but you need `position: fixed` for your footer. Apart from that, your `content` is bad positioned, remove `height` and `bottom` properties and add `min-height` and `padding-bottom` properties:

```css
.content {
    background-color: yellow;
    left: 0;
    height: calc(100% - 106px);
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 56px;
    transition: margin-left 0.5s ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: Okey, the footer is now fix in the bottom but the content (yellow color) does not go to the footer if i resize the window...

Comment: That's because of the `bottom` attribute. Use `padding-bottom` instead, just like I wrote in the answer!

Comment: In the content or in footer ?

Comment: In the content, the element with the yellow background!